# How to match and fill based on first record in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Currently have this table here:

i have two columns a URL which constantly changes and a url code - I want to take the first URL record and "fill" a new column where the URL_code matches - see outcome below

```
URL            | url_code 
---------------------------
gmail.com      | i_33
gob.com        | i_33
beans.com      | i_33
toast.com      | i_45
frog.com       | i_45
egg.com        | i_45
```

I would like to take the very first URL in the URL column for each url code, so i want to produce a table such as this:

```
URL            | url_code | taking_first_url
--------------------------------------------
gmail.com      | i_33     |  gmail.com  
gob.com        | i_33     |  gmail.com  
beans.com      | i_33     |  gmail.com  
toast.com      | i_45     |  toast.com
frog.com       | i_45     |  toast.com
egg.com        | i_45     |  toast.com
```

I have tried joining, case and when statements including LIKE in SQL but has not worked.

The url's are different - I just want to take the first one

Any ideas?

Comment: A cursor might be helpful in this case: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/cursors?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Tables are unordered sets.  Basically that means a query doesn't care in what order the records were inserted into a table. Unless you specify an ORDER BY.  So which is the first according you within the same url_code?

Comment: Not sure you understand my question - I am simply looking for a way in SQL to take the first value it finds and then just use that to fill a new column where the url code matches - this must be possible in vanilla SQL

Comment: To clarify - I just want it to extract the first URL when it reaches that first URL code - and uses the values to fill the rest of the column, up until it reaches the next URL code - then it extracts that URL and so on so forth

Comment: @DataScience is there another column in your table like a unique id with which that 1st URL can be identified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this to work, you need a column that can be used to order the records. I assume that such a column exists and is called `id`. In MySQL 8.0, you can use window function `first_value()`:

```
select
    url,
    url_code,
    first_value(url) over(partition by url_code order by id) taking_first_url
from mytable
```

In earlier versions, you could use an inline query:

```
select
    t.url,
    t.url_code,
    (select url from mytable t1 where t1.url_code = t.url_code order by id limit 1) taking_first_url
from mytable t
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ibtSq4zGsE1tzW6U61PJyT/5)**:

```
| url       | url_code | taking_first_url |
| --------- | -------- | ---------------- |
| gmail.com | i_33     | gmail.com        |
| gob.com   | i_33     | gmail.com        |
| beans.com | i_33     | gmail.com        |
| toast.com | i_45     | toast.com        |
| frog.com  | i_45     | toast.com        |
| egg.com   | i_45     | toast.com        |
```